# uiwebview orientation font size issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, font-size

I show html string in web view. In iphone 5 I am facing the problem that when I do orientation from portrait to landscape the font size of the text in uiwebview changes.

Comment: Show your html source

Comment: Load url in webview again when you change the orientation. it will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I try this and it works.
When you change the orientation load the string again to webView.

Example:
 [self.webView loadHTMLString:yourString baseURL:nil];

Its work.!!